# iPhone app crash while scheduling for local notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localnotification

I am scheduling for local notifications using code given below. I published app and it is consistantly crahsing on few user's iPhone(10% of total users) while scheduling for local notifications( Figured out using xCode crash report).

```
 let now = NSDate()


                let tomorrow = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)

                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
                let tDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tomorrow)
                let strFireDate = tDate + " 22:00:00"


                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

                if let fireDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strFireDate)
                {
                    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate

                }




                localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day


            }

           if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
               localNotification.alertTitle = "Some Text"
           } else {
               // Fallback on earlier versions
           }
            localNotification.alertBody = "Some Text."

            //localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Comment: Is your app being used in multiple countries?

Comment: Yes it is used in many countries.